# AWS CloudTrail: Can I disable S3 storage for trails, since I'm using CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudtrail

When setting up CloudTrail, you must specific a S3 bucket to store the data in.

Since I'm using CloudWatch (and CloudWatch metrics/alarms) for storage, I do not believe that I also need to store the data redundantly in S3.

Is there a reason even after configuring CloudWatch for CloudTrail, that I must also keep using S3 storage? Is there a way to turn off S3 storage for CloudTrail?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off logging for any trail:

> When you create a trail, logging is turned on automatically. You can turn off logging for a trail. Previous logs will still be accessible.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-turning-off-logging.html

Comment: I don't want to turn off logging - I don't understand why the logs are stored in both S3, and in Cloudwatch. (Why do I need both, and why can't I turn off storage in S3 and keep CloudWatch)